# порядок вызова статических блоков и конструкторов Java

Tags: java, наследование, static

Есть тестовое задание с вопросом: "Что напечатает следующий код?"
При запуске данного кода в IDE получаю следующую последовательность:
14725689
Вопрос следующий : есть какой-то порядок при котором инициализируются статические блоки/нестатические/конструкторы при наследовании?

И собственно почему именно такая последовательность получилась?

```
class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        C c = new C();
    }
}

class A {
    static {
        System.out.print("1");
    }

    A(){
        System.out.print("2");
    }

    A(String str){
        this();
        System.out.print("3");
    }
}

class B extends A {
    static {
        System.out.print("4");
    }

    B(){
        System.out.print("5");
    }

    B(String str){
        this();
        System.out.println("6");
    }
}

class C extends B {
    static {
        System.out.print("7");
    }

    {
        System.out.print("8");
    }

    C(){
        super("Hello");
        System.out.print("9");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Немного расширю предыдущий ответ

Поля объекта инициализируются в следующем порядке:

1. Статические поля класса Parent;
2. Статический блок инициализации класса Parent;
3. Статические поля класса Сhild;
4. Статический блок инициализации класса Child;
5. Нестатические поля  класса Parent;
6. Нестатический блок инициализации класса Parent;
7. Конструктор класса Parent;
8. Нестатические поля  класса Сhild;
9. Нестатический блок инициализации класса Сhild;
10. Конструктор класса Сhild.

Answer (score 2):

Сначала несколько важных замечаний.
1) Если в классе не создать конструктор, будет создан конструктор по умолчанию (без аргументов), со спецификатором доступа, как у класса:

```
public class NoConstructor {
    //конструктора нет
    //будет добавлен конструктор следующего вида
    //public NoConstructor() {
    //}
}
```

2)Первой командой конструктора должна быть this(для вызова другого конструктора) или super(для вызова конструктора суперкласса). Еслу этой команды нет - компилятор добавит ее сам. Следующий код не скомпилируется т.к. в суперклассе создан конструктор с аргументом и конструктор поумолчанию не будет создан, при этом в конструкторе подкласса нет super или this, следовательно компилятор добавляет super() - вызов несуществующего конструктора без аргумента.

```
class Parent {
    //нет конструктора без аргумента
    Parent(String s) {
    }
}
class Child extends Parent {
    //будет добавлен вызов super();
    Child(int i) {
    }
}
```

**В вашем примере порядок будет следующий:**
1. При вызове конструктора new C(), сначал производится инициализация статических членов и выполнение блоков статической инициализации. Т.к. класс имеет суперклассы, сначала инициализируются статические члены суперкласса от базового и вниз по иерархии. При этом:
1.1 Выполняется static блок в классе A - выводится "1"
1.2 Выполняется static блок в классе B - выводится "4"
1.3 Выполняется static блок в классе С - выводится "7"
2. По цепочке вызовов приходим к конструктору базового класса:
 C() {super("Hello")} -> В(String str) {this()} -> B() {super()} -> A() {...}
2.1 В базовом классе A инициализируются поля, в порядке их определения и вызаваются блоки инициализации {...}
2.2 Выполняется тело конструктор A() - выводится "2"
2.3 В классе B инициализируются поля, в порядке их определения и вызаваются блоки инициализации {...} (у вас в данном классе полей и блоков нет)
2.4 Выполняется тело конструктора B()- выводится "5"
2.5 Исполнение возвращается в конструктор B(String str)(см. пункт 2), выполняется тело конструктора - выводится "6"
2.6 В классе С инициализируются поля, в порядке их определения и вызаваются блоки инициализации {...} - выводтся "8"
2.7 Выполняется тело конструктора класса С - С()- выводится "9"

В результате получаем 14725689

Answer (score 1):

Этот [ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/846336/402815) практически корректный. Хотелось бы уточнить - что срабатывание инициализации переменных и блоков идет по их порядку в коде.

```
public class TestClass{
    public TestClass(){
        s1 = sM1("1");
    }
    static String s1 = sM1("a");
    String s3 = sM1("2");
    {
        s1 = sM1("3");
    }
    static{
        s1 = sM1("b");
    }
    static String s2 = sM1("c");
    String s4 = sM1("4");
    public static void main(String args[]){
        TestClass it = new TestClass();
    }
    private static String sM1(String s){
        System.out.println(s);  return s;
    }
}
```

собственно вывод будет

> a b c 2 3 4 1

Answer (score 0):

Порядок вызова блоков и конструктора следующий:

1. Статический блок
2. Не статический блок
3. Конструктор

Comment: Вопрос, а почему вообще появляется значение 6 в последовательности 14725689? в maine же вызывается конструктор без параметров.

Comment: @basketplayer из конструктора класса С: `super("Hello")` вызывается конструктор класса В со строковым параметром.

Comment: Ок, а почему идет значение 8 после 6, а не 9 следом после вызова super("Hello") из конструктора класса C?